# multiple instance of same function in C

Tags: c

I am using C for the Arduino controller and I have a function that contains a static variable inside

```
int buttonReallyPressed(int i);
```

I want multiple instances of that function so I have done this:

```
typedef int (*ButtonDebounceFunction) ( int arg1);
ButtonDebounceFunction Button1Pressed = buttonReallyPressed;
ButtonDebounceFunction Button2Pressed = buttonReallyPressed;
```

Have I received two separate instances of the function int buttonReallyPressed(int i)?

Comment: Nope, just two pointers to the same function.  C has **no** concept of "instance of a function".

Comment: "I want multiple instances of that function". Why? What are you hoping to achieve with this?

Comment: @Paul OP explained why: Because they want two separate copies of the static variables declared inside the function.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for an explanation of why they wanted that, as there's probably a different way of achieving the real purpose

Comment: Use a static array instead of a single static variable in the function?

Comment: Create structure holding everything you need to handle single button (move static variable into it). Create many instances of that structure (button1_ctx, button2_ctx). Pass the structure to button handler as parameter. That is.

Answer (score 5):

When you create pointer to function, you don't create another instance of static variable in the function.

Workaround is: create structure holding everything you need to handle single button (move static variable into it). Create array of instances of the structure. Pass the structure to button handler as parameter.

```
struct button_state {
    int pressed; // or whatever
}

struct button_state button[3];

int buttonReallyPressed(struct button_state *state);

void button_isr(...)
{
    ...
    buttonReallyPressed(&button[id]);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you have two pointers to the same function.

Comment: @LasseKaragiannis See alexander's comment above.  He has the right idea.  A C function with static variable in its scope is effectively a singleton pattern instance.  If you want object instance behavior, you must implement it yourself.